# Iptables allow only certain ips to an specific site

Tags: firewall, iptables, website

I would like to allow certain IPs to a site running under my apache server (`my.site.com`). I know I can do it using `Allow from 192.168.0` but I'm wondering if it is possible doing it through `iptables` and at the same time log the requests made to `my.site.com` using an iptables rule. What would that set of rules be?

Answer (score 1):

```
#access control

iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -s 192.168.0.0/24 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -j DROP

#loggin
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -m string --to 200 --string "GET /" --algo kmp -j LOG
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -m string --to 200 --string "POST /" --algo kmp -j LOG
```

Answer (score 0):

The `string` match extension will allow you to do some filtering on the contents of a packet, but you're really better off doing it in httpd.

Comment: Thanks. Any particular reason why not doing it in httpd?